# Find IP range with RegEx

Tags: sql, regex, ip, vertica

I have an input of an IPV4 address and its prefix(from 1-32).
My output should be somthing like:

```
input:172.194.11.80/24

output: 172.194.11.0-172.194.11.255
```

I'm doing this via VERTICA (SQL)

My question is this something I should do with RegEx?
Or should I build a function that does this?

Comment: As long as it's not numerically dependent (which requires numeric logic) it's simply this find `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*` replace `$1.0-$1.255`

Comment: sin thanks for the response, this logic wont work because the prefix is dynamic.

Comment: By prefix, do you mean the 3 first dot-separated digit groups? That is, is , in your case, `172.192.11` the prefix?
And would `80/24` have any meaning - or would you just ignore the last  bit? 
And I don't see any hint to " from 1-32" in your input example. What am I missing?